# For loop to convert strings based on last word not running

Tags: python, pandas, string, for-loop, split

I am trying to write a for-loop in python on a pandas dataframe. I want to convert all strings in the color column that have "Green" as their last word (ex. Yellowish Green") to just "Green". Below is my loop:

```
for color in df['color']:
    low = color.split()
    if low[-1] == "Green":
        color = "Green"
```

However, this is not changing the actual values in the dataframe.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
def transform(string):
    last_word = string.split()[-1]
    if last_word.lower() == 'green':
        return 'green'
    else:
        return string

df['color'] = df['color'].apply(transform)
```

Answer (score 1):

For loops in Python iterate over the values and not references of whatever you're iterating over. You could use list comprehensions instead:

```py
df['color'] = ["Green" if x.split()[-1] == "Green" else x for x in df['color']]
```

Or if the word green isn't necessarily capitalized:

```py
df['color'] = ["Green" if x.split()[-1].lower() == "green" else x for x in df['color']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#text-string-methods).

```
mask = df['Color'].str.endswith('Green')
df.loc[mask,'Color'] = 'Green'
```